# How to fetch subscription daily breakdown through API for Google Play

Tags: c#, google-play, google-play-console, subscription, google-play-developer-api

i can download the CSV file in the subscription overview in google play console .

[image]

i want to be able to access the report and filter based on products/date through an API.

all search results lead to use subscription.list or subscription.get after getting the service .

but this is not what is needed .